# Measuring non-commuting properties on entangled particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Suppose we start with an entangled quantum state such that two particle spins are always perfectly correlated so that $S_{ax} = S_{bx}$ and $S_{az} = S_{bz}$. Suppose I measure $S_{ax}$ = +1 and $S_{bz}$ = -1 simultaneously. Then can't I infer that at the time of those measurements, we have the following: 
$S_{ax}$ = +1, $S_{az}$ = -1, and $S_{bx}$ = +1, $S_{bz}$ = -1? Both of these would be violations of the uncertainty relations for spin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we know in advance $S_{ax}=S_{bx}$ and $S_{az}=S_{bz}$, then $[S_{ax},S_{bz}]\neq 0$. You cannot measure those two simultaneously without uncertainty.

Comment: Wow, nice observation. But doesn't this indicate nonlocality since the x measurement of a interferes with the z measurement of b and vice versa?